# Can open camera but not able to display other activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, camera

I can able to open `camera` but not able to display other activity.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(data.getData() != null){
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        }else{
            Log.d("selectedPath1 : ","Came here its null !";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed to get Image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data";
            selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            //  EditPhotoActivity.start(this,selectedPath);;
            Log.d("selectedPath1 : " ,selectedPath);
        }

        if (requestCode == 10)
        {
            selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            EditPhotoActivity.start(this,selectedPath);
            Log.d("selectedPath1 : " ,selectedPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can u explain clearly that what is your problem? and what errors u getting?

Comment: share  java file